# Does OpenSC required proprietary Gemalto SafeNet middleware to support Gemalto IDPrime card?

Tags: smartcard

I am interesting by buying a Gemalto IDPrime MD 830 card to be used onto two computers in various scenarios:
- Storing certificate (Windows, Linux)
- Authentication (Linux)

The Windows computer would be accessed by multiple operators always in the same session.

I contacted a Gemalto reseller and he told me Gemalto SafeNet's (and obvisously its license) is required. And I would need to buy as many licenses as the number of card - with a minimum of 25 licenses.
I also read I would be able to use this card for free on Windows through the Microsoft Minidriver.

I am familiar with OpenPGP cards and the 'easy/free' way to provision a card. I thought using another card would be similar in the sense I buy a card reader and a card and I can use it to store keys and certificates.

Comment: Nö you don’t need the middleware (you might need drivers for card readers)

Comment: On OpenSC wiki https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-have-a-pkcs11-compatible-smart-card-can-i-use-it-with-opensc they said "I have a PKCS#11 compatible smart card. Can I use it with OpenSC? Not necessarily. PKCS#11 is a software interface, it means the vendor provides a PKCS#11 module with their hardware. " And the Gemalto card is not in the list of supported card: https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-%28smart-cards-and-USB-tokens%29#generic-smart-cards

Comment: Hm, I thought I used it without, but maybe it was a Windows driver. The MD cards load them via Windows Update automatically.